# How to handel data for android apps

Tags: java, android-studio

i have lot of data like GenericName, BrandName, CompanyName, RegNumber. there are hundreds of GenericName. Every GenericName has lots of BrandName, CompanyName, RegName.
it actually like Medicine Data. How may i handel It inside android apps with Android Studio JAVA programming. please help.....

Comment: Try looking at [JSON in Android - Tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html).

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are facing? What have you tried? What do you expect to happen?